# Netbeans libraries contains different jar/class than directed to

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, netbeans7.0

I have been trying to follow the [Getting Started with JAX-WS Web Services](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html). I had a lot of trouble because JDK 6 has JAX-WS 2.1 but METRO has JAX-WS 2.2 . So with a lot of searching I found out that something called "[endorsed](http://metro.java.net/guide/Using_JAX_WS_2_1_with_JavaSE6.html)" exists. I try to work with apache and I found out about the JAX-WS clash (see PS2 hyperlink 3). Now I have an endorsed folder with 2 .jar files in it: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\jre\lib\endorsed" containing "jaxb-api.jar" and "jaxws-api.jar". And finally everything seemed to work, but unfortunately only for the 'server-application'. After a lot of searching and copying different files to the endorsed folder and again and again... ...I started to think something is wrong with Netbeans instead of me being stupid. So i downloaded a java decompiler (see PS2 hyperlink 4), and looked in the jar-files in the endorsed folder. Btw, the errors I am recievin in Netbeans are that the javax.xml.ws.Service does not also contain the following constructor:

```
protected Service(URL wsdlDocumentLocation, QName serviceName, WebServiceFeature[] features)
```

but only the following constructor:

```
protected Service(URL wsdlDocumentLocation, QName serviceName)
```

I set a in netbeans to contain the two jar files in the endorsed folder, but when I expand them and open the 'Service' class, the constructor with 3 arguments is not there. BUT(here comes the strange part) when I decompile the class service in the jar file "jaxws-api.jar" in the endorsed file, it DOES contain that constructor.

So netbeans does not use the jar file referenced to by a library? Or what is going on(and more importantly, how can I fix it)?

I checked where the class is located by "Service.class.getClassLoader()" (pasted it from somewhere I cant remember):

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.endorsed.dirs"));
final URL location;
final String classLocation = Service.class.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class";
final ClassLoader loader = Service.class.getClassLoader();
if(loader == null){
    System.out.println("Cannot load the class");
}else{
    location = loader.getResource(classLocation);
    System.out.println("Class " + location);
}
```

But this gives me the output:"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\jre\lib\endorsed" and on the second line "Cannot load the class". 
So while running, it cant load the class, but netbeans shows in its projects window in the proyect->Libraries when I expand the library containing the 'endorsed jar-files' to the Service class that it is there. And when I open it I get no error, just not the file containing the right constructor

To summarize: I think that netbeans ignores the jar file I tell it to use and gets its own jar file somewhere, but does not show it to me...

PS: some specs

Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.0 (Build 201104080000)
Java: 1.6.0_21; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 17.0-b17
System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on amd64;
Tests with Apache Tomcat 7.0.11 (I don't think this is of any use)

Hope to solve this mystery,
Tjen

PS2: i can only post 2 hyperlinks so here are number 3 and 4 (include your own http://):

3: weblogs.java.net/blog/ramapulavarthi/archive/2009/04/tip_for_using_j.html

4: java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui

Comment: If you are having problems with jars I would suggest you to use maven and add to maven project the required dependencies

Comment: I am unfamiliar with maven, have heard of it though. I'll look into it.